# (Rails) radio buttons not lining up with text

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I want `ff.label` to line up with `ff.radio_button.` But right now my view has them extremely far apart and not lined up. Why? 
[image]
I've added a css tag to this question in case it's a problem with css and not rails just in case.

this is my code:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @submitted_quiz]) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :quiz_id, :value => @quiz.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => @quiz.name %>

<% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>
<div class = "questions" >
<%= f.label question.content %>

<%= f.fields_for (:submitted_answers) do |ff| %>

<%= ff.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question.id %>
<div class = 'options'>
<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
<div class = 'radio'>
<%= ff.radio_button :content, answer.content %>
<%= ff.label :content, answer.content %>

</div>
<% end #answer.each do %>
</div>
<% end #fields_for (:submitted_answers) do %>

</div>
<% end #questions.each do %>


<%= f.submit %>
<% end #form_for  %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your radio button inside your label and try.

```
<div class="radio">
  <%= ff.label :content do %>
    <%= ff.radio_button :content, answer.content %>
    <%= answer.content %> <!-- this will make the text appear after the radio button -->
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Update:**

Like this

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" ... /> 
  Foo
</label>
```

Here `Foo` will appear right after the radio button not before.

Comment: Hey I don't know what that would do, why would I want the closing `div` to end after my loop?  

I fixed the alignment issue by putting the whole thing in a `row` with `col-md-6` but not sure if that was the right thing to do. Also they're still spaced quite far apart.

Comment: The point of wrapping your radio button with a label is, when you click on the text the radio button will listen to it. If you don't do that, you'll have to click on the radio dot to select it. Try it.

Comment: actually I didn't solve the distance issue after all (alignment issue was solved). And I could already do that (click on the text to select the radio button) before.

Comment: do you know why my radio button appears after my label though? I feel like that's related to my distance issue.

Comment: Its how you put it. You put the label first and then the radio button. Or wrap your radio inside label, and put the label's content after the radio, just like I answered.

Comment: oh yeah I see it now, I think I misunderstood you the first time I looked at it. Thank you!

Comment: You're most welcome! You may remove the the `col-md-6` and maybe give it a try. I think it will align just right.